# Converting from list comprehension back to for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
     mins = X.min().values #array of min vals
     maxs = X.max().values #array of max vals   
     test = []
     test = {
            i: [np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t]) for t in range(len(mins))]
            for i in range(k)
        }
```

or this

```
for c in range(k):
     indices = [distances.index(row) for row in distances if row[-1] == c]         
     test[c] = X.iloc[indices].mean().values
```

Is it possible to convert this list comprehension back to for loops in python? I'm relatively new to python and am having issues with the syntax.

Comment: `{i: ... for i in range(k) }` is actually a dictionary-comprehension. But the inner-portion is a list.

Comment: unrelated: `[np.random.randint(min_val,max_val) for min_val,max_val in zip(mins,max)]` .. I despise indexing ....

Comment: is it possible to convert this to for loops? @Jeppe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically just work backwards, so to start with you have:

## code 1

```
{i: [np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t]) for t in range(len(mins))] for i in range(k)}
```

So the first step is `for i in range(k)` to generate your keys, followed by something to do with generating a list, or:

```
result = {}
for i in range(k):
    temp = [] 
    # something to do with making a list
    result[i] = temp
```

Then working backwards again you have `for t in range(len(mins))` leaving just the `np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t])` bit

So:

```
result = {}
for i in range(k):
    temp = []
    for t in range(len(mins)):
        temp.append(np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t]))
    result[i] = temp
```

In a full code example it would be

```
import numpy as np
mins = [1, 2, 3, 4]
maxs = [5, 6, 7, 8]
k = 3
test = []
test = {
    i: [np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t]) for t in range(len(mins))] for i in range(k)
    }
print(test)

result = {}
for i in range(k):
    temp = []
    for t in range(len(mins)):
        temp.append(np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t]))
    result[i] = temp
print(result)
```

Where the first is your comprehension and the second is in for loops. The results:

```
{0: [3, 3, 3, 4], 1: [2, 4, 3, 6], 2: [3, 2, 3, 5]}
{0: [4, 3, 4, 4], 1: [3, 3, 4, 4], 2: [3, 2, 6, 4]}
```

You can see we have achieved the same results by deconstructing the comprehension from right to left!

## case 2

```
indices = [distances.index(row) for row in distances if row[-1] == c]
```

Can be decomposed the same way. Starting at the back-most `for` we find:

```
for row in distances if row[-1] == c
```

Which equates to:

```
for row in distances:
    if row[-1] == c
        #do something
```

We know it is all wrapped in a list, so adding in a list and appending the "something" to it is pretty straightforward:

```
indices = []
for row in distances:
    if row[-1] == c:
        indices.append(distances.index(row))
```

Note that I haven't tested this one though (and it's also impossible to do so with the information given)

If we put this into the original code block of

```
for c in range(k):
    indices = [distances.index(row) for row in distances if row[-1] == c]        
    test[c] = X.iloc[indices].mean().values
```

We now have

```
for c in range(k):
    indices = []
    for row in distances:
        if row[-1] == c:
            indices.append(distances.index(row))        
     test[c] = X.iloc[indices].mean().values
```

Comment: what about the second one?

Comment: @AdvaitKulkarni What about the second one? I need more context related to your question...

Comment: converting this one:  for c in range(k):
     indices = [distances.index(row) for row in distances if row[-1] == c]         
     test[c] = X.iloc[indices].mean().values

Comment: does the test[c] = X.iloc[indices].... go outside of the for row loop? @Reedinationer

Comment: @AdvaitKulkarni That is not a list comprehension. It would be separate

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```py
test = {}
for i in range(k):
  test[i] = []
  for t in range(len(mins)):
    test[i].append(np.random.randint(mins[t], maxs[t]))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it says list assignment index out of range for test[i] = []

Comment: @AdvaitKulkarni Initialize `test` as `test = {}`, and it will work.

Comment: got it, thanks @Jeppe . Is it possible for the other one as well?